# jQuery load method is loading multiple div instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right logged">
            my content...           
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row">               
        <div class="col-md-12">         
            <div class="post">

                <div class="load-me">
                    main cotent
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

now, I have login and logout functionality. when I log in I need to reload the content of this `<div class="load-me"></div>` as I need to show some dynamic content. Same thing I need for the logout process.

For this I am using the following jQuery code:

for logout...

```
success : function ( data ) {
    $(".logged").html( logged_area );
    $(".post").html('').load(location.href + " .load-me"); // this line...
}
```

for login...

```
success : function ( data ) {
    $(".login-message").html( data );               
    $(".post").html('').load(location.href + " .load-me");
}
```

But it's loading **that div** 2 times as you can see it here: http://creativeartbd.com/demo/facebook/

**Use this when login:** alexbd / 123456789

Note: there are only 2 posts

Comment: u might need either `.hide()` or `.empty()` or `.html("")` the div vice versa on login and logout

Comment: There are two elements with class `load-me`, don't know what do you expect? Check your response.